# Guidance, VBA - SELECT CASE clean up

Tags: ms-access, vba

This `SELECT CASE` scenario is working for me but I think the code can be more friendly ... any advice would be very helpful.

```
Select Case True 'select case where worker name and action is true then in each case RSworkhours.addnew

    Case Me.Worker1.Value <> "" And Me.fw1a1 = 1
        With RsWorkHours
            .AddNew
            !WorkerID = Me.Worker1
            !Date = Me.TxtDate
            !StandardTime = Me.w1a1s
            !Overtime = Me.w1a1o
            !Doubletime = Me.w1a1d
            !ScaffoldID = Me.cboScaffnum
            .Update
        End With
        Me.fw1a1 = 0
        GoTo WorkerHours
   Case Me.Worker1.Value <> "" And Me.fw1a2 = 1
        With RsWorkHours
            .AddNew
            !WorkerID = Me.Worker1
            !Date = Me.TxtDate
            !StandardTime = Me.w1a2s
            !Overtime = Me.w1a2o
            !Doubletime = Me.w1a2d
            !ScaffoldID = Me.cboScaffnum
            .Update
        End With
        Me.fw1a2 = 0
        GoTo WorkerHours
```

The Code iterates through this `Select Case` 80 times, if there are 16 workers and each have 5 actions.

I was thinking maybe having a loop that modifies the number within the arguments like:

```
for each x to 16
    for each y to 5
        If Me.worker & x & .Value <> "" And Me.fw & x & a & y Then
            With Recordset
                .AddNew
                'insert stuff
                .Update
            End With
        End If
    Next y
Next x
```

Does anyone have any insight? 
Thank you in advance.

-Matt
[image: ATTACHED IS AN IMAGE OF THE FORM JUST TO GET AN UNDERSTANDING OF WHAT THE CODE IS DOING.]

Comment: Are you sure that this is the best possible UI for your use case?

Comment: Further to what @Tomalak said, what happens if "Worker 1" ever has a 6th Action?

Comment: In this case yes, this is only half of the form in Design view... this is a `_Click` event for each combobox that expands the form as needed and this form is only good for one set of circumstances that will only ever have a max of 5 actions in a day.... 
That being Said, I am always up for suggestion in how to streamline my forms and programs.

Comment: Thank you @Andre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access all controls by their name from the [`Controls` collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445317(v=vs.60).aspx).

Just pass the name of a control and you will get to that control - the name is a string and can of course be dynamic.

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim WorkerX As Control, wXaYs As Control, wXaYo As Control, wXaYd As Control

For x = 1 To 16
    For y = 1 To 5
        Set WorkerX = Me.Controls("Worker" & x)
        Set wXaYs = Me.Controls("w" & x & "a" & y & "s")
        Set wXaYo = Me.Controls("w" & x & "a" & y & "o")
        Set wXaYd = Me.Controls("w" & x & "a" & y & "d")
        If WorkerX.Value > "" And wXaYs.Value > "" Then
            With Recordset
                .AddNew
                !WorkerID = WorkerX.Value
                !Date = Me.TxtDate
                !StandardTime = wXaYs.Value
                !Overtime = wXaYo.Value
                !Doubletime = wXaYd.Value
                !ScaffoldID = Me.cboScaffnum
                .Update
            End With
        End If
    Next y
Next x
```